# PyQt with c++ classes

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt

i want to use from PyQt application classes (lib/tool) written on c++ with Qt usage. I searched for solution and found Boost.python. Is it a good decision or there are a better tools for this purpose?

Thank you,

Kenn

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Python should be the easiest way, yes.